# Trying to integrate Azure Graph API in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

when requesting the method of `GetAllUsers`, I get this error

> TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng' from assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Comment: Please share a little more details about your code being used to call this method `GetAllUsers`. Also are you trying to use `Microsoft Graph API` or `Azure AD Graph API`? For most cases Microsoft Graph API would be recommended.. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/

Comment: Have you referred to this sample?https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect-aspnetcore/  If you could provide more details about your issue, we can help you further.

Comment: whic version of .net core are you targeting ?

Comment: need more details here